# General way to find out whether a curve is positively oriented

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, plane-curves

I have a general question, that deals with the question how I am able to find out whether a particular curve(in $\mathbb{C}$) is positively oriented?  Take e.g. $ y(t)=a+re^{it}$. Obviously this one is positively oriented, but is there a fast general method to proof this?

Comment: By convention, a positively oriented curve is one such that, when traveling on it, one always has the curve interior to the left.

Comment: yeah, but I do not always want to draw a picture in order to find this out ;-)

Comment: You need to add the condition that the curve is closed and simple. The unit interval [0,1] has no orientation, while the figure 8 goes from being positively to negatively oriented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question you are asking is how to prove that the [turning number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turning_number) of a simple closed curve is equal to one.  This is the same as saying that the [winding number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number) of the curve is one around any point lying inside the curve.

There are several ways to do this, and none of them is particularly fast.  Here are some possibilities:

1. One basic possibility is to make a graph of $\arg(\gamma'(t))$.  If the argument increases by $2\pi$ as you go once around the curve (ignoring any jumps from $\pi$ to $-\pi$ on your graph), then the curve is positively oriented.  Similarly, if $p$ is any point lying inside the curve, you could make a graph of $\arg(\gamma(t) - p)$ and do the same thing.  Of course, both of these involve drawing a graph, which you may prefer not to do.
   On a related note, given a closed curve $\gamma\colon [a,b]\to\mathbb{C}$, if you can find a continuous function $\varphi\colon [a,b]\to \mathbb{C}$ so that $\gamma'(t) = e^{\varphi(t)}$, then the curve is positively oriented if and only if $\varphi(b)-\varphi(a)=2\pi i$, and negatively oriented if and only if $\varphi(b)-\varphi(a)=-2\pi i$.  This is certainly the fastest way of dealing with the example you gave.
   Similarly, if $p$ is any point inside the curve, you could find a function $\varphi(t)$ so that $\gamma(t) - p =e^{\varphi(t)}$, and perform the same test.
2. Assuming the curve $\gamma\colon [a,b]\to \mathbb{C}$ is twice differentiable (with the derivatives at $a$ and $b$ matching up) and has no critical points, you can integrate the curvature of the curve along its length:
   $$
   \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_a^b \frac{d}{dt}[\arg(\gamma'(t))]\,dt \;=\; \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_a^b \frac{\mathrm{Re}[i\,\gamma'(t)\,\gamma''(t)]}{|\gamma'(t)|^2} dt,
   $$
   This integral will come out to $+1$ if the curve is positively oriented, and $-1$ if the curve is negatively oriented.
3. If $p$ is a point lying inside the curve, you can use an integral to compute the winding number around $p$.  This requires that the curve $\gamma\colon [a,b]\to \mathbb{C}$ be differentiable:
   $$
   \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_a^b \frac{d}{dt}[\arg(\gamma(t)-p)]\,dt \;=\; \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_a^b \frac{\mathrm{Re}[i\,(\gamma(t)-p)\,\gamma'(t)]}{|\gamma(t)-p|^2} dt,
   $$
   Again, this integral will come out to $+1$ if the curve is positively oriented, and $-1$ if the curve is negatively oriented.  By the way, if this integral comes out to $0$ it means that the point $p$ you chose does not lie inside the curve.  Indeed, you can use this integral to test whether a given point lies inside a given closed curve.
4. You can compute the degree of $\gamma'$ as a sum of local degrees.  Specifically, let $\theta$ be any fixed angle, and let $t_1,\ldots,t_n$ be the values of $t$ for which $\arg(\gamma'(t)) = \theta$.  For each $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, let
   $$
   d_k \;=\; \begin{cases}+1 & \text{if }\mathrm{Im}(e^{-i\theta}\gamma''(t_k))>0 \\[6pt] -1 & \text{if }\mathrm{Im}(e^{-i\theta}\gamma''(t_k))<0 \end{cases}
   $$
   (If the imaginary part every comes out to zero, you should probably just choose a different value of $\theta$.)  Then the sum
   $$
   d_1 + \cdots + d_n
   $$
   will be $+1$ if the curve is positively oriented, and $-1$ if the curve is negatively oriented.
   This test is easier to apply than it looks.  For many curves, there will only be one value of $t$ for which $\arg(\gamma'(t)) = \theta$, so you only need to check whether $\mathrm{Im}(e^{-i\theta}\gamma'(t))$ is positive or negative for this one value of $t$.
5. Similarly, if $p$ is a point lying inside the curve, you can compute the winding number of $\gamma$ around $p$ using a sum of local degrees. Specifically, let $\theta$ be any fixed angle, and let $t_1,\ldots,t_n$ be the values of $t$ for which $\arg(\gamma(t)-p) = \theta$.  For each $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, let
   $$
   d_k \;=\; \begin{cases}+1 & \text{if }\mathrm{Im}(e^{-i\theta}\gamma'(t_k))>0 \\[6pt] -1 & \text{if }\mathrm{Im}(e^{-i\theta}\gamma'(t_k))<0 \end{cases}
   $$
   (If the imaginary part every comes out to zero, you should probably just choose a different value of $\theta$.)  Then the sum
   $$
   d_1 + \cdots + d_n
   $$
   will be $+1$ if the curve is positively oriented, and $-1$ if the curve is negatively oriented.
   Again, this test is easier to apply than it looks, since there is often just one value.  As with test #3, if the sum comes out to $0$ it means that the point $p$ does not in fact lie in the interior of the curve.
6. Given a differentiable curve $\gamma\colon [a,b] \to \mathbb{C}$, find a partition of $[a,b]$ into intervals $I_1,\ldots,I_n$ with the following property: for each $k$, the image of $\gamma'$ on the closure of $I_k$ lies in one of the following half-planes:
   $$
   H_0 = \{\mathrm{Re}(z) > 0\},\quad H_1 = \{\mathrm{Im}(z) > 0\},\quad H_2 = \{\mathrm{Re}(z) < 0\},\quad H_3 = \{\mathrm{Im}(z) < 0\}.
   $$
   Note that these half-planes overlap, so you don't need to be particularly careful in choosing your partition.  For each $k$, let $m_k\in \{0,1,2,3\}$ be the number of the half-plane containing $I_k$.  For each transition $(m_k,m_{k+1})$, label it $+1$ if $m_{k+1} \equiv m_k +1 (\mathrm{mod}\;4)$, and $-1$ if $m_{k+1} \equiv m_k - 1 (\mathrm{mod}\;4)$.  Then your curve is positively oriented if there are more $+1$ transitions than $-1$'s and negatively oriented if there are more $-1$ transitions than $+1$'s.
   A similar approach can be used on $\gamma(t)-p$ instead to compute the winding number, where $p$ is a point inside of the curve.

Answer (score 1):

Orientation only really applies to simple, closed curves.

For a general curve, you might find the winding number to be useful.

See: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContourWindingNumber.html